If leader failed to run in Solr, can we promote one of the followers as a leader?
If leader failed to run in Solr, can we promote one of the followers as a leader?
I have three followers.

I don't think that is possible using a leader/follower setup, but SolrCloud is basically doing exactly this . You do not chose actively choose a leader, the leader is dynamically chosen by ZooKeeper, if the chose one goes down a different node will be elected as leader.
